# Gitlab CI/CD deploy a stage just once

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to execute a stage just once, only the first time that the pipeline is executed

For example, if I have this stages

- build
- tag_version
- test
- deploy

I wanna execute **N** pipelines but without execute 'tag_version' the next times, just execute it at the first time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rules: changes`, maybe combined with `when: manual`, so that the tag is executed only when a specific file is changed (say, the Dockerfile).

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the following rule, catching the push event and matching with my tag that I wanna tag. In this way my stage is executed once

```
.mycondition: &mycondition
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^release-v\d+$/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: always
```